# Plone 4 comments ordering

Tags: plone, viewlets

I don't want to use any product to manage my comments
I use basic feature
So, the older comment is displayed in first (and of course the last at the bottom)
what i have to do to have contrary in Plone 4.0.4 ? (the last comment at the top of the comments)

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Comments order is managed in `plone.app.layout.viewlets.comment`:

http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/plone.app.layout/trunk/plone/app/layout/viewlets/comments.py#L28

If you want to re-sort the comments you should override or change the original behavior of `getRs` method. The final implementation depends on what do you want to do with replies to last comment.

Do you want replies to be also re-sorted? If so, I think that just changing the sort function should work:

```py
rs.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(y.modified(), x.modified()))
```

Do you want replies to keep original sort? In that case, you should code a little more.